# API Integration WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, session-cookies

I have to integrate the vendor API that is in php i think. I have to perform following steps

1- Handshake the API that will give salt and sessionID, and also set the cookie vendor.com ii.

2- generate the token based on `HMAC MD5` for every subsequent request and send the token in get request.
i have done the above but the problem is every time i request the server for say search it returns `token mismatch error`

My code is below.

```
class APIManager
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    CookieCollection responseCookies = new CookieCollection();

    private async Task<string> httpRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        string received;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory
            .FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    cookieJar = request.CookieContainer;
                    responseCookies = response.Cookies;
                    received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        return received;
    }

    public async Task<string> Get(string path)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

        return await httpRequest(request);
    }

    public async Task<string> Post(string path, string postdata)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path)) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
        using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null))
        {
            await requestStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return await httpRequest(request);
    }

}
```

I talked to vendor and they say that i need to preserve the session cookie vendor.com ii 
in my code above i am assigning the cookie jar to next request (search) but still it is returning same error.

In browser it works fine, below is the screenshot of cookies i am recieving in browser. Also the image shows the cookies received in my `HttpWebRequest` cookiejar shows count 4 but cookie collection doesn't show any count. Is it the problem?
[image]